# How to use the color picker dialog to set color properties in the property editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

This sounds like a trivial question, but it's proved quite hard to google anything about this.

When editing Color-typed properties through the property editor (when designing WinForms), a little editor pops up with three tabs: Custom, Web and System. I want to set a custom color by using the standard color picker dialog because none of the listed Custom colors are suitable.

I am sure that this used to be possible by double-clicking a blank color on the Custom tab, but this just picks the color being double-clicked and closes the drop-down in my VS2008. Am I imagining this, or did it really use to be possible? Can I do this in VS2008 somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on a blank colour in the palette shown by the custom tab. Brings up the "Define Color" dialog (in VS2008 C# Express, and I imagine the same in other versions).

EDIT - Having discovered this by experimentation, the MSDN library describes it [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewzh0y4y.aspx)
Interestingly, no keyboard-only interface is described.

Comment: Thanks very much, this works! I tried double clicking the colors and right clicking the field, but not right-clicking the colors...